# unity android sdk error

Tags: unity, android, export

[image: s this the image]i am using unity 18.x.
i downloaded the android sdk itself and the android studio also but they are not working,unity is not detecting the android sdk.
if anyone succceed in exporting the apk successfully.
kindly,provide the sdk folder here (request) 
god will bless you if you share the folder here,
because i am trying to export it since 5 month.
and if i try to update the sdk from unity the unity stucks and do not respond. i waited for few hours to respond but,
it does not respond.
please provide the sdk folder here.
i am begging please
and its also not detecting the android sdk in android studio folder 
instead of suggesting please share  the android sdk folder here .
please share the folder here so others who is also having the same issue  download the sdk from  here.
i know this is a silly question  but its a huge problem for me now
**for more  informmation: i also have  the 19.3f1f version and not installed  the microsoft redistributable i used to launch unity from  the hub**

Comment: Please take the time to format your question for legibility. Punctuation, spelling, and paragraph breaks are much more important for getting help than promises of a deity's blessing.

Comment: ok i am editing it

Comment: When you read your post before submitting it, look at the rendered output, not the edit box. Users read the rendered output, so _that_ is what is important.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to set SDK API  version in Unity platform

Or Run Studio and update all required tools and platform

Or check out the path of SDK download PATH : C:/USERS/USERNAME/APPDATA/SDK default PATH

Open SDK MANAGER 
Check Install PATH dir....